# Keeping users logged in without cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I was wondering if there was any other way to keep users logged in when they revisit my website even though the session has expired.

I currently use a cookie based method, but I was wondering if there were other methods people are using.

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/is-it-correct-to-use-form-fieldhidden-for-storing-session-token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no [reliable] methods beside a cookie.

Comment: I would agree on this one :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense If cookie is disabled, can I use an extra HTTP header to store some kind of token? Essentially mimic the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

There are other methods, but you should refrain from using them because they in no way are as reliable as cookies.

- You can use a IP based login system. If using this, you will see issues with multiple users from same IP.
- You can generate a special link for users that is uniquely generated and make a login based on that

Instead of worrying about doing it another way, you should work on making your cookie-using system more secure.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but for the sake of future visitors, I would like to supply an answer.

You **SHOULD** use cookies. Like the other answers have noted, they are the most reliable method out there. If you want to make sure the user isn't visiting with an expired cookie, write the time at which it expires as a cookie with a checksum.

Here's an example using PHP:

```
$expireTime = time() + (60*60*24*3); // 3 days ( 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 3 days )
$rawPepper = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$hexPepper = bin2hex($rawPepper);
setCookie($cookieKey, $cookieValue, $expireTime);
setCookie("expiresWhen", $expireTime, $expireTime);
setCookie("rand", $hexPepper, $expireTime);
$hash_1 =  hash('sha512', "Your_Super_Secret_Salt" . $cookieValue . "Another_Super_Secret_Salt!" . $expireTime);
$hash_2 = hash('sha512', "Yet_Another_Salt!" . $hash_1. $hexPepper);
setCookie("checksum", $hash_2, $expireTime);
```

Then in your other PHP form for validation you say:

```
$expires = $_COOKIE['expiresWhen'];
$pepper = $_COOKIE['rand'];
$cookieVal = $_COOKIE[$cookieKey];
$givenCheckSum = $_COOKIE['checksum'];

$hash_1 = hash('sha512', "Your_Super_Secret_Salt" . $cookieVal . "Another_Super_Secret_Salt!" . $expires);
$correctCheckSum = hash('sha512', "Yet_Another_Salt!" . $hash_1. $pepper)

if($givenCheckSum != $correctCheckSum){
      /* user's cookie has expired. Handle as you please */
}else{
     /* Cookie is still valid */
}
```

Anyone care to make corrections to this or supply suggestions?